# Running 'npm update ejs --depth 2', to fix security vulnerabilities does nothing

Tags: npm, resolution, npm-update

In the pipeline I get a message:

> Check package security issues

It tells me `# Run  npm update ejs --depth 2  to resolve 1 vulnerability`.

This is the description tabel:

```
High          │ Template injection in ejs                                    │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Package       │ ejs                                                          │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Dependency of │ source-map-explorer                                          │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Path          │ source-map-explorer > ejs                                    │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ More info     │ https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-phwq-j96m-2c2q
```

But when I run this command I don't get any changed files appearing?

I know I can add `ejs` to resolutions inside my `package.json` like:

```
"resolutions": {
    "ejs": "3.1.7",
}
```

But why does `npm update ejs --depth 2` does nothing?